# What is the best way to add an optional length argument?

Tags: r

First post ever, excuse my ignorance as I'm relatively new to programming. I'm trying to create a function that samples a number given by x and returns "number too small" below 5 and "number too big" if its above 10. I already figured this part out, however my issue is that I want to add an optional len argument that will display the length of x if used and if not will still function as intended. I'm sure its possible if I just do a bunch of if else statements with every possible scenario, but is there a more organized way to achieve my goal. Was thinking that I can make another if/else that returns null if they opt out of the second len argument but unsure on how i would code it as I already have two if or else statements.

```
vector.maker.num2 <-function(x){
  generator <-sample(1:20, x)
  if (x < 5) {
    print(c(generator, "warning, number too low"))
  }
  if (x > 10) {
    print(c(generator, "warning, number too high"))
  } 
} 

vector.maker.num2(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is the `missing` function.

```
vector.maker.num2 <-function(x, len){
  generator <-sample(1:20, x)
  if (!missing(len)) {
    print(length(x))#Will usually print 1, because x is a vector of length 1.
  }
  if (x < 5) {
    print(c(generator, "warning, number too low"))
  }
  if (x > 10) {
    print(c(generator, "warning, number too high"))
  } 
} 

vector.maker.num2(4)
```